List of anime reference in this meme
I would like to know all anime series referenced in this video (timestamps 0:03 to 0:23). I can recognize few but not all. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

0:03 (Mushoku Tensei), 0:06 (Fate Stay/Night, Berserk), 0:07 (Beastars, One Piece), 0:08 (Naruto, Persona 5), 0:09 (Boku no Hero Academia, Naruto) 0:10 (Fate Stay/Night), 0:11 (Chainsaw Man), 0:12 (K-ON), 0:13 (Pocket Monsters 2019), 0:14 (Re:Zero kara Hajimeru Isekai Seikatsu), 0:15 (Ijiranaide Nagatoro-san, Kobayashi-san Chi no Maid Dragon, Bleach), 0:16 (DBZ, Mushoku Tensei), 0:18 (Fate Stay/Night, Tate no Yuusha, Sailor Moon), 0:19 (Kobayashi-san Chi no Maid Dragon, KonoSuba, Evangelion)
